# Byte array to brush Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, arrays

i found a lot of answers on Stackoverflow or internet, but noone of them solved my problem.
the closest solution i found was a mix of some and resulted in this:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
{
    writer.WriteBytes(foto.FOTO_BYTE);
    writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
}
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(stream);
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = image;
preview.Background = brush;
```

The second part works, because i already used it in another application and i did it, but in Windows 8.1 i have a problem converting the `byte[]` into an `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`.

Anyway help will be appreciated.

PS: `new WriteableBitmapImage(bitmap);` doesn't work in WP 8.1 :(

Thanks all.

EDIT: `preview` is a canvas, may it be the wrong way to fill it?
this is how i initialize it

```
<Grid x:Name="rootView">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas x:Name="preview" Background="White" Grid.Row="0"></Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="btnElimina" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Content="ELIMINA"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this

```cs
public static class ByteArrayExtensions
{
    public static async Task<BitmapImage> AsBitmapImageAsync(this byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (byteArray == null) return null;

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            stream.Seek(0);
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same as the other answer, i see it working but it doesn't fill the canvas, i posted the code, u think i'm missing something?

Comment: my guess would be that canvas isnt stretching, add horizontal and vertical alignment to stretch

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for conversion you want :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
internal static async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> ConvertTo(byte[] arr)
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(arr.AsBuffer());
    randomAccessStream.Seek(0);

    return randomAccessStream;
}
```

Comment: i don't know why, the code seems work but  i can't see anything in the canvas, i post the code i created it with, i'm missing something?

Comment: Just to make clear, this code is for converting byte array to InMemoryRandomAccessStream. You need to make Bitmap from it

Comment: Yeah, i tryed it with a code working in wp 8.0 (not universal app) but the same code with a bitmap generated from this inMemoryRandomAccessStream show me a black canvas :/

Comment: Did you use WP 8? You asked for Windows 8.1. Try to reinstall your app and check

Comment: No wait, i missexplained: i have a piece of code took from 8.0 app, the code i'm working with now is 8.1. If you check my question, the last 5 rows of code are the ones i'm using to convert inrandom to bitmap and assigning it to background, but they are not working with the code you posted and i don't know why..